# Why alertdialog can not dismiss?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

What's wrong with this code? Why I can't dismiss alert dialog when pressed on `ok`

```
 protected void loadDialogBox(Context context, String title, String message) {
    try {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
        dialogBuilder.setMessage(message);          
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            Log.i(TAG,"Ok is clicked");
            fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
            dialogInterface.dismiss();

        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just try to move up line `dialogInterface.dismiss();`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code it's not necessary to call dismiss setting the positive and negative button automatically dismiss dialog after onclick is completed:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                dialogBuilder.setTitle("New Item");
                dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter Item Details");
                dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    }
                });
                dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        //pass
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
                b.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change code to

```
protected void loadDialogBox(Context context, String title, String message) {
    try {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new 
        AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
        dialogBuilder.setMessage(message);   
       final AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();       
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            Log.i(TAG,"Ok is clicked");
            fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
            dialog.dismiss();

        });

        dialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```